# I am trying to create an hasable struct. but every time getting " MyNewHasableStruct does not conform to protocol Hashable "

Tags: swift

Following is the code snippet I am having an issue with.
What I understand about Hasbale is that it should comfort '==' and 'hashValue' but due to the error I have override '<' also but still facing the same issue.

```
struct MyNewHasableStruct {
    let oneString: String
    let oneInt: Int
}

extension MyNewHasableStruct : Hashable {
    var hasValue : Int {
        return oneString.hashValue ^ oneInt.hashValue
    }

    static func == (lhs: MyNewHasableStruct, rhs: MyNewHasableStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.oneInt == rhs.oneInt && lhs.oneString == rhs.oneString
    }


   static func < (lhs: MyNewHasableStruct, rhs: MyNewHasableStruct) -> Bool {
       return lhs.oneInt < rhs.oneInt && lhs.oneString < rhs.oneString
   }

}
```

Comment: Because of your `typo`. That var should be `hashValue` not `hasValue`.

Answer (score 0):

`var hasValue : Int` should be `var hashValue : Int`

```
struct MyNewHasableStruct {
        let oneString: String
        let oneInt: Int
    }

    extension MyNewHasableStruct : Hashable {
        var hashValue : Int {
            return oneString.hashValue ^ oneInt.hashValue
        }

        static func == (lhs: MyNewHasableStruct, rhs: MyNewHasableStruct) -> Bool {
            return lhs.oneInt == rhs.oneInt && lhs.oneString == rhs.oneString
        }


       static func < (lhs: MyNewHasableStruct, rhs: MyNewHasableStruct) -> Bool {
           return lhs.oneInt < rhs.oneInt && lhs.oneString < rhs.oneString
       }

    }
```